# How do I use my list in an "if" loop?

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I want to create a new window with a `if` and a list in the `if`, in first, my list is empty, but when we click on `button1`, `button2` or `button3` it add the value of the color list, if it's "yellow", "red" or "green" and in this program, my goal is to have 2 balls of the color in 3 attempt but when I run my program it says that my list is "out of range",(Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Arnold Tchiasso/Desktop/g2.py", line 91, in 
    if liste[0]==liste[1]:
IndexError: list index out of range) I show you:

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import shuffle

fenetre = tk.Tk()
fenetre['bg']='black'
fenetre.geometry("1152x768")
color = ["red", "green", "yellow"]
shuffle(color)
liste=[]

frameGauche = tk.Frame(width=200, height=600, bg='pink')
frameGauche.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

frameDroite = tk.Frame(width=700, height=700, bg='grey')
frameDroite.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

portegauche=tk.Frame(frameDroite, width=200, 
height=600,bg='white',bd=5,relief='groove')
portegauche.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

portemilieu=tk.Frame(frameDroite, width=200, 
height=600,bg='white',bd=5,relief='groove')
portemilieu.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

portedroite=tk.Frame(frameDroite, width=200, 
height=600,bg='white',bd=5,relief='groove')
portedroite.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

canvas1=tk.Canvas(portegauche,width=200, height=600, bg='white')
c1 = canvas1.create_oval((60,280), (140,340), width=1, outline="black", fill=color[0])
canvas1.grid_forget()

canvas2=tk.Canvas(portemilieu,width=200, height=600, bg='white')
c2 = canvas2.create_oval((60,280), (140,340), width=1, outline="black", fill=color[1])
canvas2.grid_forget()

canvas3=tk.Canvas(portedroite,width=200, height=600, bg='white')
c3 = canvas3.create_oval((60,280), (140,340), width=1, outline="black", fill=color[2])
canvas3.grid_forget()

def normalize_button(btn_name):
    print(btn_name)
    if btn_name == "b1":
        bouton1['state']='normal'
    if btn_name == "b2":
        bouton2['state']='normal'
    if btn_name == "b3":
        bouton3['state']='normal'

def show1():
    canvas1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    bouton2['state']='disabled'
    bouton3['state']='disabled'
    fenetre.after(2000, normalize_button, "b2")
    fenetre.after(2000, normalize_button, "b3")
    fenetre.after(2000, canvas1.grid_forget)
    shuffle(color)
    liste.append(color[0])
    print(liste)

def show2():
    canvas2.grid(row=0, column=2)
    bouton1['state']='disabled'
    bouton3['state']='disabled'
    fenetre.after(2000, normalize_button, "b1")
    fenetre.after(2000, normalize_button, "b3")
    fenetre.after(2000, canvas2.grid_forget)
    shuffle(color)
    liste.append(color[1])
    print(liste)

def show3():
    canvas3.grid(row=0, column=3)
    bouton2['state']='disabled'
    bouton1['state']='disabled'
    fenetre.after(2000, normalize_button, "b2")
    fenetre.after(2000, normalize_button, "b1")
    fenetre.after(2000, canvas3.grid_forget)
    shuffle(color)
    liste.append(color[2])
    print(liste)

def recommencer():
    canvas1.grid_remove()
    canvas2.grid_remove()
    canvas3.grid_remove()
    shuffle(color)
    canvas1.create_oval((60,280), (140,340), width=1, outline="black", fill=color[0])
    canvas2.create_oval((60,280), (140,340), width=1, outline="black", fill=color[1])
    canvas3.create_oval((60,280), (140,340), width=1, outline="black", fill=color[2])
    bouton1['state']='normal'
    bouton2['state']='normal'
    bouton3['state']='normal'

if liste[0]==liste[1]:
    top = tk.Toplevel()
    top.title("C'est gagné")
    lab1=tk.Label(top, text="WIN")
if liste[0]==liste[2]:
    top = tk.Toplevel()
    top.title("C'est gagné")
    lab1=tk.Label(top, text="WIN")
if liste[1]==liste[2]:
    top = tk.Toplevel()
    top.title("C'est gagné")
    lab1=tk.Label(top, text="WIN")

boutonR = tk.Button(frameGauche, text='Recommencer',command=recommencer)
boutonR.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=50, pady=50)

bouton1=tk.Button(frameDroite, text= 'Ouvrir',command=show1)
bouton1.grid(row=1, column=0)

bouton2=tk.Button(frameDroite, text= 'Ouvrir',command=show2)
bouton2.grid(row=1, column=1)

bouton3=tk.Button(frameDroite, text= 'Ouvrir',command=show3)
bouton3.grid(row=1, column=2)



fenetre.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback from the exception. Is the indentation of the three `if` blocks correct? Are they meant to be part of the `recommencer` function?

Comment: you have to make sure your list contains enough item to support the comparison.  Are you calling trying to compare list indexes before they have been added to the list?

Comment: Sorry if you don't understand what i'm saying, it's a little game that I want to make by myself, here is the traceback:

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Arnold Tchiasso/Desktop/g2.py", line 91, in <module>
    if liste[0]==liste[1]:
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: you set `liste = []` and then try to access the `0` and `1` slot without adding anything to it... Also edit your post with the error not commenting.

Comment: So I have to create my list into the functions `if` ?

Comment: At line 91, when you try to look at some values in the list, the list is empty. You are trying to look at the first and second values of nothing. Before you look at it, you must add something to it.Translation into French via Google Translate: À la ligne 91, lorsque vous essayez d'examiner certaines valeurs dans la liste, la liste est vide. Vous essayez de regarder les première et deuxième valeurs de rien. Avant de le regarder, vous devez ajouter quelque chose.

Comment: Yes, i saw that, that is what i'm trying to fix right now, can I begin like this `.append([None, None, None])`